# Proof for checking correctness of the multiplication result

Tags: formal-proofs

Yesterday I was reading a topic about arithmetic and accidentally came across with an interesting way to verify the multiplication of two numbers.

For example, let's say i have
$$123\times 456=56088$$
and i doubt with this answer, so i want to verify that the result is correct. So, i have to show the implication : **"If the digits sum of the multiplier times the digits sum of the multiplicand is equal to the digits sum of the result, then the result is correct"** is true.

1. Digits sum of the multiplier $123$ $\Rightarrow \, 1+2+3=6$
2. Digits sum of the multiplicand $456$ $\Rightarrow \, 4+5+6=15$ $\Rightarrow 1+5 = 6$
3. Digits sum of the product of those digits $\Rightarrow 6\times 6=36$ $\Rightarrow 3+6=9$
4. Digits sum of the result product $56088$ $\Rightarrow 5+6+0+8+8=27$ $\Rightarrow 2+7=9$
5. Since $9=9$, then the product of those two numbers is correct.

I searched for proof about this to convince me so i can use it whenever i need it, but i got nothing. Have you ever seen the proof of this statement formally?

Comment: Well, the iterated digit sum is (essentially) just the number $\pmod 9$ (the only difference is that the $0$ residue is represented by $9$), so...

Comment: But the implication is false. $1\times1=10$ would pass this test, whilst being quite clearly wrong.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No. $1\times 1=10$ ? Really? $1\times 1=1$ the digit sum is $1$ and the product is $1$ as well.

Comment: @lulu can you tell me more specifically? I know a bit about $\pmod$ and residue anyway.

Comment: My point, 516076, is that if you tried to multiply $1\times1$ and somehow came up with the answer $10$, the test you propose would tell you that you have the right answer. Maybe a less trivial example will convince you: if you got $56808$ as the answer when you did $123\times456$, your test would tell you the answer you got is correct – when, of course, it isn't. Oh, what @lulu wrote relies upon the congruence $a+10b+100c+1000d+\cdots\equiv a+b+c+d+\cdots\bmod9$.

Comment: To stress what Gerry Myerson wrote, the check here is just that we verify the product $]pmod 9$.  You could check it $\pmod 5$ or $\mod {17}$ or whatever but it just so happens that there is an easy way to check it $\pmod 9$ (by adding the digits).  Of course that doesn't prove the product was correct but if you just made a blunder in producing the product there is a $\frac 89$ chance that you'll have messed it up $\pmod 9$ as well (speaking roughly).

Comment: You might be interested in reading about "casting out nines": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines

Comment: Do you understand, 516076?

Comment: Are you still here, 516076?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, late reply. I just opened this forum.  Thank you, i understand.

Comment: Good. You could write up your understanding, and post it as an answer.